# RecordType selection list not available in $A.get("e.force:createRecord")

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, create-records, force

I'm trying to create a Contract from an Opportunity record via **$A.get("e.force:createRecord")** but it's not displaying RecordType selection list.

User has access to two different RecordTypes so it must be displayed.

The issue is that we've used **$A.get("e.force:createRecord")** to overwritte **New** button for Contract and it's showing RecordType selection list, but this quickAction for Contract creation from Opportunity (previously mentioned) it's not replacating same behaviour.

What could be causing this? Do I need to display RecordType selection list as a custom development?

Our org is in Summer '19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> force:createRecord opens a page to create a record for the specified
>   entityApiName, for example, "Account", or "myNamespace__MyObject__c".

To display the record create page for an object, set the object name on the entityApiName attribute and fire the event. **recordTypeId is optional and, if provided, specifies the record type for the created object**. defaultFieldValues is optional and, if provided, specifies values to use to prepopulate the create record form.

So If you want to show the record type selection, you have do some extra stuff something like this:- [Custom Record Type Selection Lightning Component with force:createRecord event](http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/05/09/custom-record-type-selection-lightning-component/)

As per idea([Support Record type selection in custom Lightning component and custom VF pages](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CR9sQAG)) raised for this:-

> Currently force:createRecord and sforce.one.createRecord take in a
>   recordTypeId from the developer or use the default record type if none
>   is specified. Salesforce plans to look at providing an option to
>   display the out of the box record type selector in the future.

You can up vote the above idea so that Salesforce consider this as priority.

Comment: Thanks, we've created custom component and now it's working as desired!